# append another div when one div reaches its end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show a div when one div reaches to the end.I have tried it but its not working properly.can any one help on this.(align the text inside div(#right) into several lines so that you will get a vertical scrool bar and try)

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var bot=$('#right')[0].scrollHeight;
        var pos=$("#right")[0].scrollTop +$("#right")[0].clientHeight;

        if(bot==pos){

            $("#footer").css("display","block");
        }
        alert("End");
    });
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">

     #left{
         width:10px;
         height:100px;
         overflow:hidden;background-color:blue;
      }

      #right{
         width:52px;
         height:100px;
         overflow:auto;
         background-color:green;
         position:absolute; 
         top:7px;
         left:20px;
      }

      #footer{
         width:50px;
         height:50px;
         background-color:yellow;
      }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

     <div id="left"></div>

        <div id="right">
         abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
        </div>

     <div id="footer" style="display:none"></div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MbZq8/)

Comment: jsfiddle this, what you have posted is riduculous

Comment: How is this related to css-selectors?

Comment: @DavidB,align the text inside div(#right) into several lines,so that you will get a vertical scroll bar,now Jsfiddle that.